# Access LongListSelector DataTemplate controls programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm targeting Windows Phone 8 and I would like to access my `StackPanel` named ListHeaderStackPanel which resides in a `LongListSelector` `DataTemplate`. My code looks as follows

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListHeader">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <StackPanel x:Name="ListHeaderStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="8">
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Is this possible? I've tried using `FindName` without luck and simply using ListHeaderStackPanel from code will not work.

Comment: You can try using the `VisualTreeHelper` class to walk the Visual Tree. There's a generic implementation here that may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/5191681/187697

Comment: I've tried it by passing in my LongListSelector and LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate, both of them, unfortunately, returned null for StackPanel item.

Comment: I just tried it and it's working for me: `HelperClass.FindDescendant<StackPanel>(lls.ListHeaderTemplate.LoadContent());` Don't forget, it's generally a good idea to try and take advantage of DataBinding when possible (if that's the reason you're trying to access the control).

Comment: Ah, I passed in the DataTemplate directly and not the DependencyObject from LoadContent(). It works now, thank you!

Comment: Another quick question: Do I have to reload my LongListSelector template after adding children to my StackPanel? I add some content but it wont show up. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test at the moment but this post might help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846273/adding-children-to-stackpanel-programmatically-not-working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28811/discussion-between-markus-persson-and-keyboardp)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have time but you could post it as a new question and someone else might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `VisualTreeHelper`, that keyboardP suggested in the first comment, to find the `StackPanel`.

> You can try using the VisualTreeHelper class to walk the Visual Tree.
>   There's a generic implementation here that may help
>   stackoverflow.com/a/5191681/187697

Comment: Hi , I am also using LLS , can u please give the solution to access a element inside the LLS Data templete.